# Ansible AWX step fails when using DSL for Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm running a Jenkins 2.140 server on Ubuntu 16.04 as well as an Ansible AWX 1.0.7.2 server using Ansible 2.6.2.

I'm creating a job in Jenkins which runs a template on my Ansible AWX server. I've got several other Jenkins jobs that run templates that all work so I know the general configuration I am using for this is OK.

However when I create the Jenkins job using a seed job which uses the JobDSL, the job fails at the Ansible AWX step with this output:

```
11:50:42 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
11:50:42 Building remotely on windows-slave (excel Windows orqaheadless windows) in workspace C:\JenkinsSlave\workspace\create-ec2-instance-2
11:50:42 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
11:50:42 java.lang.NullPointerException
11:50:42    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible_tower.AnsibleTower.perform(AnsibleTower.java:129)
11:50:42    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
11:50:42    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
11:50:42 Build step 'Ansible Tower' marked build as failure
11:50:42 [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
11:50:42 [BFA] No failure causes found
11:50:42 [BFA] Done. 0s
11:50:42 Started calculate disk usage of build
11:50:42 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
11:50:42 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
11:50:42 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
11:50:42 Finished: FAILURE
```

That output doesn't really give me anything to work with especially as I'm no Java expert.

I configure the Jenkins job manually and all is well. This is the `config.xml` for the working job (only the AWX part). Note that all of these extra variables are passed in earlier in the job as parameters:

```
<builders>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible__tower.AnsibleTower plugin="ansible-tower@0.9.0">
<towerServer>AWX Server</towerServer>
<jobTemplate>create-ec2-instance</jobTemplate>
<extraVars>
key_name: ${key_name} ec2_termination_protection: ${ec2_termination_protection} vpc_subnet_id: ${vpc_subnet_id} security_groups: ${security_groups} instance_type: ${instance_type} instance_profile_name: ${instance_profile_name} assign_public_ip: ${assign_public_ip} region: ${region} image: ${image} instance_tags: ${instance_tags} ec2_wait_for_create: ${ec2_wait_for_create} ec2_wait_for_create_timeout: ${ec2_wait_for_create_timeout} exact_count: ${exact_count} delete_volume_on_termination: ${delete_volume_on_termination} data_disk_size: ${data_disk_size} private_domain: ${private_domain} route53_private_record_ttl: ${route53_private_record_ttl} dns_record: ${dns_record} elastic_ip: ${elastic_ip}
</extraVars>
<jobTags/>
<skipJobTags/>
<jobType>run</jobType>
<limit/>
<inventory/>
<credential/>
<verbose>true</verbose>
<importTowerLogs>true</importTowerLogs>
<removeColor>false</removeColor>
<templateType>job</templateType>
<importWorkflowChildLogs>false</importWorkflowChildLogs>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible__tower.AnsibleTower>
</builders>
```

And the `config.xml` from the failing, JobDSL-generated job, which looks the same to me:

```
<builders>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible__tower.AnsibleTower>
<towerServer>AWX Server</towerServer>
<jobTemplate>create-ec2-instance</jobTemplate>
<jobType>run</jobType>
<templateType>job</templateType>
<extraVars>
key_name: ${key_name} ec2_termination_protection: ${ec2_termination_protection} vpc_subnet_id: ${vpc_subnet_id} security_groups: ${security_groups} instance_type: ${instance_type} instance_profile_name: ${instance_profile_name} assign_public_ip: ${assign_public_ip} region: ${region} image: ${image} instance_tags: ${instance_tags} ec2_wait_for_create: ${ec2_wait_for_create} ec2_wait_for_create_timeout: ${ec2_wait_for_create_timeout} exact_count: ${exact_count} delete_volume_on_termination: ${delete_volume_on_termination} data_disk_size: ${data_disk_size} private_domain: ${private_domain} route53_private_record_ttl: ${route53_private_record_ttl} dns_record: ${dns_record} elastic_ip: ${elastic_ip}
</extraVars>
<verbose>true</verbose>
<importTowerLogs>true</importTowerLogs>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible__tower.AnsibleTower>
</builders>
```

So there are some expected differences you always get with JobDSL-generated jobs, such as the empty fields are missing, but this is the case with all of our (successful) other jobs that follow this process.

The JobDSL script is here:

```
    configure { project ->
        project / 'builders ' << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible__tower.AnsibleTower' {
            towerServer 'AWX Server'
            jobTemplate ('create-ec2-instance')
            templateType 'job'
            jobType 'run'
            extraVars('''key_name: ${key_name} 
ec2_termination_protection: ${ec2_termination_protection} 
vpc_subnet_id: ${vpc_subnet_id} 
security_groups: ${security_groups} 
instance_type: ${instance_type} 
instance_profile_name: ${instance_profile_name} 
assign_public_ip: ${assign_public_ip} 
region: ${region} image: ${image} 
instance_tags: ${instance_tags} 
ec2_wait_for_create: ${ec2_wait_for_create} 
ec2_wait_for_create_timeout: ${ec2_wait_for_create_timeout} 
exact_count: ${exact_count} 
delete_volume_on_termination: ${delete_volume_on_termination} 
data_disk_size: ${data_disk_size} 
private_domain: ${private_domain} 
route53_private_record_ttl: ${route53_private_record_ttl} 
dns_record: ${dns_record} 
elastic_ip: ${elastic_ip}''')
            verbose 'true'
            importTowerLogs 'true'
        }
    }
```

The job that this generates *looks* identical in the UI (as well as the XML) to my eye, and yet I keep getting that failure when I run it. Clearly I'm missing something but I can't for the life if me see what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that other AWX jobs build without this, I added the missing (empty) fields, and the job started succeeding.

So, change my JobDSL script to this:

```
    configure { project ->
        project / 'builders ' << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible__tower.AnsibleTower' {
            towerServer 'AWX Server'
            jobTemplate ('create-ec2-instance')
            extraVars('''key_name: ${key_name} 
ec2_termination_protection: ${ec2_termination_protection} 
vpc_subnet_id: ${vpc_subnet_id} 
security_groups: ${security_groups} 
instance_type: ${instance_type} 
instance_profile_name: ${instance_profile_name} 
assign_public_ip: ${assign_public_ip} 
region: ${region} 
image: ${image} 
instance_tags: ${instance_tags} 
ec2_wait_for_create: ${ec2_wait_for_create} 
ec2_wait_for_create_timeout: ${ec2_wait_for_create_timeout} 
exact_count: ${exact_count} 
delete_volume_on_termination: ${delete_volume_on_termination} 
data_disk_size: ${data_disk_size} 
private_domain: ${private_domain} 
route53_private_record_ttl: ${route53_private_record_ttl} 
dns_record: ${dns_record} 
elastic_ip: ${elastic_ip}''')
            jobTags ''
            skipJobTags ''
            jobType 'run'
            limit ''
            inventory ''
            credential ''
            verbose 'true'
            importTowerLogs 'true'
            removeColor ''
            templateType 'job'
            importWorkflowChildLogs ''
```

And now working as expected.